# how to get Arabic in Photoshop CS3?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, arabic

I want to type Arabic text in Photoshop cs3, but the text appears disjointed and the letters do not connect at all. For example محمد appears as م ح م د.

Answer (score 0):

Download any arabic font style from Google and then right click on FONT TTF File to Install font to your PC.

Run Photoshop

you will be having arabic font in Photoshop.

see this video link for your answer
http://youtu.be/QXMbIA6apFw

Comment: Hi @bapugraphics, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Please do not link to your own site's main page if it doesn't contain a specific answer to the question. Self-promotion is what your profile is for :). Moreover, could you please provide an excerpt of the solution in the YouTube video your other link points to? In that way, your answer is still valuable when the link breaks or the video goes down later. Thanks!